# C# manipulating data parsed from CSV

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, data-manipulation

I'm creating a program to generate schematics based off of user input. This has to be done dynamically/by hand due to the sheer volume of different possibilities (6.8M, growing exponentially). Right now I'm working on importing some data via CSV.

Example data:

```
Type,TIN_pos,TIN_ID,Desc
Elect, 0, X, Manual Regulator
Elect, 0, A, Electronic Regulator
```

Import code:

```
List<TIN_Fields> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Visual Basic\\CSV_Test_1.csv")
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(v => TIN_Fields.FromCsv(v))
                    .ToList();

public class TIN_Fields
{
    public string Type;
    public int TIN_pos;
    public string TIN_ID;
    public string Desc;

    public static TIN_Fields FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        TIN_Fields _Fields = new TIN_Fields();
        _Fields.Type = Convert.ToString(values[0]);
        _Fields.TIN_pos = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);
        _Fields.TIN_ID = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
        _Fields.Desc = Convert.ToString(values[3]);
        return _Fields;
    }
}
```

Once that data is Imported, I need to do two things with it,

1. display the raw csv data in a ListView table, just so users can see if anything in the list needs updating.
2. be able to compare the items in the list to various characters in a 10-digit hexadecimal code, and spit out some results.

First and foremost, i need to run through the list that was created with the above code, make sure that:

TIN_pos value = 0

because that is the character position of the input box.

Then, with the remaining options, look for the character represented in the input in the TIN_ID field.
Once found, it should then output the Desc field.

Everywhere I have looked says to use foreach, but that requires the array name, which is the part that is confusing me. I've tried filling in basically all of the variables in the FromCSV Method and usually get an error that the class doesn't have a definition.

to hopefully clear up confusion with my explanation, here is the code I created that does the same thing, but with the CSV data hard coded into it, using switch cases and if statements.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string Model_Chassis;
        public string Model_Test_Type;
        public int ChannelNumberVar => Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_TIN[2]);
        public string Tester_Type_Selector;
        public string TextBox_TIN 
        {
            get { return TIN_Entry_TextBox.Text; }
            set { TIN_Entry_TextBox.Text = value; }
        }

        public string Model_Data_D
        {
            get { return Model_Data.Text; }
            set { Model_Data.Text = value; }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //Method grabs TIN Box data and decodes it to model information.
        public void Model_Select()
        {
            //Picks Model Chassis
            switch (char.ToUpper(TextBox_TIN[0]))
            {
                case 'H':
                    {
                        Model_Chassis = Coding.Model1.description;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        Model_Data_D = "INVALID TIN";
                    }
                    break;

            }

            //Picks Test Type
            switch (char.ToUpper(TextBox_TIN[3]))
            {
                case '0':
                    {
                        Model_Test_Type = Test_Types.TT_PD.TT_tt;
                    }
                    break;
                case '1':
                    {
                        Model_Test_Type = Test_Types.TT_PV.TT_tt;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    {
                        Model_Test_Type = "";
                    }
                    break;
            }

            //Puts chassis and Test Type together
            if (Model_Data_D.Equals("INVALID TIN"))
            {
                ;
            }
            else if (char.ToUpper(TextBox_TIN[2]).Equals(Coding.Num_Chan_1_2.tin_id))
            {
                Model_Data_D = $"{Model_Chassis}-{Model_Test_Type}";
            }
            else
            {
                Model_Data_D = $"{Model_Chassis}-{TextBox_TIN[2]}{Model_Test_Type}";
            }
        }
    public class Coding
    {
        public char tin_id;
        public string description;

        public Coding(char TIN_ID, string Desc)
        {
            tin_id = TIN_ID;
            description = Desc;
        }

       public static Coding Model1 = new Coding('H', "Model1");
       public static Coding Num_Chan_1_2 = new Coding('X', "Single Channel");
       public static Coding Elect_Reg_F_1 = new Coding('X', "Manual Regulator");
     }
  }
```

INPUT:

```
HXX0X
```

OUTPUT

```
Model1-PD
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking quite a few questions, and providing a lot of extra details in here, but for this:

"First and foremost, i need to run through the list that was created with the above code, make sure that:
TIN_pos value = 0
because that is the character position of the input box."

(seeing as you say you need to do this 'first and foremost').

In your `FromCsv` method, check the value as you create the record, and throw an error if it is invalid. Like this:

```
 public static TIN_Fields FromCsv(string csvLine)
    {
        string[] values = csvLine.Split(',');
        TIN_Fields _Fields = new TIN_Fields();
        _Fields.Type = Convert.ToString(values[0]);

        _Fields.TIN_pos = Convert.ToInt16(values[1]);

        if(_Fields.TIN_pos != 0){
            throw new Exception("TIN_pos must be 0");
        }

        _Fields.TIN_ID = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
        _Fields.Desc = Convert.ToString(values[3]);
        return _Fields;
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've read in your CSV correctly, which it seems you have, then selecting the appropriate TIN from the list is a simple LINQ statement. The following code assumes that TIN IDs are unique and only a single character in length.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testCsv = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Visual Basic\CSV_Test_1.csv";

        List<TIN_Fields> values = File.ReadAllLines(testCsv)
               .Skip(1)
               .Select(v => TIN_Fields.FromCsv(v))
               .ToList();

        // Simulates input received from form
        string input = "HXX0X";

        TIN_Fields selectedTIN = values.First(x => x.TIN_ID == Convert.ToString(input[0]));

        // Insert the description as needed in your ouput.
        string output = $"{ selectedTIN.Desc }-";

    }
```

Hopefully that answers another part of the problem. The `Convert.ToString()` is required because the output of `input[0]` is a `char`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! the TIN_ID aren't unique, but I got it to work by using an AND statement in the LINQ statement.```TIN_Fields STIN_0 = values.Find(x => x.TIN_pos == "0" && x.TIN_ID == Convert.ToString(char.ToUpper(TIN_Text[0])));```